# How do I specify scons alias dependencies?

Tags: python, build, scons

I have an alias that builds some packages, called `'build_packages'`. This alias won't build, however, unless a specific transcoder library is built before it: `'transcoderLib'`. `'transcoderLib'` is an alias as well, and builds just fine by itself. I tried specifying my alias dependencies like so:

```
env.Alias('transcoderLib')
...
Default(env.Alias('build_packages'))
Depends('build_packages', 'transcoderLib')
```

If I then build `'build_packages'`, `'transcoderLib'` is not built at all and the build fails, since `'build_packages'` depends on it. Why is scons not picking up the dependency?

Further information: At the point where I declare both of these aliases, neither of them has any targets yet, they are simply empty aliases which are filled by SConscripts later. I expect `Depends('build_packages', 'transcoderLib')` to define a dependency from `'build_packages'` on `'transcoderLib'`, so that `'transcoderLib'` is built first and then `'build_packages'` is built.

EDIT: To add to this confusion, I found that when I used `scons --tree=derived,prune`, it prints out all the correct dependencies for `'build_packages'`! If it sees the dependencies, why isn't it building them?!!! Here is the build tree itself (pruned of course, NDAs and such):

```
+-build_packages
  +-Build\Config\Package_1
  | +-Package_1_Dependencies...
  +-Build\Config\Package_2
  | +-Package_2_Dependencies...
  ...etc... for 16+ packages...
  +-transcoderLib
    +-Build\Transcoder.dll
    | +-DLL dependencies...
    +-Build\Transcoder.lib
    | +-LIB dependencies
    +-Build\Transcoder.exp
    | +-EXP depdendencies
    +-Lib\Python\Transcoder.pyd
      +-[Build\Transcoder.dll]
      +-[Build\Transcoder.lib]
      +-[Build\Transcoder.exp]
```

EDIT 3: To provide a more complete example, I've arranged a simple SConstruct that mimicks the situation I have rather well (I deleted the previous example in EDIT 2 to avoid confusion). The real problem is that a Python file is importing the 'transcoderLib' target, so scons doesn't even know it needs to build the library before building packages. I'm trying to tell scons it is necessary. Here's the simple example:

```
import SCons
import shutil
import os

env = Environment(tools=['default', 'textfile'])

def package_builder(target, source, env):
  cmdLine = 'python test.py'
  return os.system(cmdLine)

def copy(env, target, source):
  shutil.copy(source[0].path, target[0].path)
env.Append(BUILDERS = { 'copybuilder' : Builder(action = Action(copy, ' COPY $SOURCE -> $TARGET')) } )
env.Append(BUILDERS = { 'package' : Builder(action = Action(package_builder, ' PACKAGE $SOURCES -> $TARGET'), suffix='.zip' ) } )

env.Textfile(target='foo.txt', source='hello, world\n')

config = int(ARGUMENTS.get('config', 0))
if config == 1:
  Default(env.Alias('build_packages'))
  Depends(env.Alias('build_packages'), env.Alias('transcoderLib'))

env.Alias('transcoderLib', 'foo.txt')
copyTarget = env.copybuilder('bar.txt', 'foo.txt')
env.Alias('transcoderLib', copyTarget)

package = env.package('#Test', [])
env.Alias('build_packages', package)
```

and of course test.py, which is an extremely simple script that depends on bar.txt, the target of 'transcoderLib':

```
import os
if not os.path.exists('bar.txt'):
  raise Exception("bar.txt wasn't created yet!")
```

and the output:

```
scons: warning: Support for pre-2.7.0 Python version (2.6.2) is deprecated.
    If this will cause hardship, contact dev@scons.tigris.org.
File "C:\Python26\Scripts\scons.py", line 192, in 
scons: Building targets ...
 PACKAGE  -> Test.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in 
    raise Exception("bar.txt wasn't created yet!")
Exception: bar.txt wasn't created yet!
scons: *** [Test.zip] Error 1
```

Of course, if I 'scons transcoderLib' first, it builds 'bar.txt' just fine, and I can run 'scons config=1' without error. For those wondering why I'm using a builder without any sources or targets, it's to keep my example as simple as possible. The 'package' builder should simply run 'test.py' (in reality, it also builds the package, but the package's dependencies are completely isolated from the 'transcoderLib').

Comment: Can you provide a short, complete example of a failing SConstruct? [My attempt](http://ideone.com/jFREtj) works exactly as you'd expect. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Robᵩ I've posted code above for the SConstruct, and it is failing still. Your example will also fail I think, if you actually built something in the 'build_packages' alias. Eventually 'transcoderLib' would get built in my complicated example, but the point is it needs to be built FIRST.

Comment: Your example is misleading because you don't have a Builder defined/used for actually creating your target "build_packages". Note, that in SCons your implicit dependencies (a header like foo.h) are added to the target which gets built (foo.o in this case). Simply defining an Alias only, which is *not* a dependency, won't do.... If you care about simple modules and programs (= your packages?) that get built from libraries, all you have to do is specify those libnames and -paths properly via the LIBS and LIBPATH variables (check SCons' excellent UserGuide) and things should run out-of-the-box.

Comment: @dirkbaechle So 'transcoderLib' is built using a LoadableModule builder, and then the real dependency is on it being copied to the correct location using a custom copybuilder (which just calls shutil copy). If that copy builder is called in a SConscript separate from the package SConscripts, how can I assign dependency to that copybuilder?

Comment: @dirkbaechle I posted a more accurate SConstruct above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You setup wrong dependencies, if I understood correctly what you're trying to achieve. I tried to amend your SConstruct from EDIT 3 above, as follows:

```
import SCons
import shutil
import os

env = Environment(tools=['default', 'textfile'])

def package_builder(target, source, env):
  cmdLine = 'python test.py'
  return os.system(cmdLine)

def copy(env, target, source):
  shutil.copy(source[0].path, target[0].path)
env.Append(BUILDERS = { 'copybuilder' : Builder(action = Action(copy, ' COPY $SOURCE -> $TARGET')) } )
env.Append(BUILDERS = { 'package' : Builder(action = Action(package_builder, ' PACKAGE $SOURCES -> $TARGET'), suffix='.zip' ) } )

env.Textfile(target='foo.txt', source='hello, world\n')

#
# Here the changes start
#

# The following line is not needed, SCons picks up the
# dependency bar.txt -> foo.txt automatically
#tclib = env.Alias('transcoderLib', 'foo.txt')
copyTarget = env.copybuilder('bar.txt', 'foo.txt')
# Defining Alias for later reference...
# important: don't create new Alias()es all over
#            the place, but pass a single reference around
tclib = env.Alias('transcoderLib', copyTarget)

# Main change: Your initial dependencies were wrong, it's
# the package (='python test.py') that depends on your
# transcoderLib (='bar.txt')...
package = env.package('#Test', [])
env.Depends(package, tclib)

# Create an Alias for the packages, you can pass
# a list of all your packages too here...
bp = env.Alias('build_packages', package)

# Finally, set the package Alias() as default target if
# requested by the config parameter...
config = int(ARGUMENTS.get('config', 0))
if config == 1:
  env.Default(bp)
```

It correctly builds 'bar.txt' first, before trying to run the 'package' step. Note that on an update, the 'package' Builder gets called again and again, because the specified target "#Test" never gets created...so it's always regarded to be out-of-date.

I hope this helps you further, or at least gives you a few new ideas if this isn't the solution you've been looking for.

Final remark: Simply adding a required dependency collectively to all your packages, by adding it to an Alias that contains your packages, won't work. Your Alias is regarded as a different target, so if you call "scons package_1" to build a single package...the dependency won't kick in. You have to be explicit and add the dependency to each package, because that's how your build structure looks like.

Comment: It turns out I was blocking the generation of required files with an if statement... your answer is completely correct. *slaps self*

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `env.Alias()` sets up a dependency, not an equivalency. So when you say that build_packages depends upon transcoderLib, you are **not** saying that bar.txt also depends upon transcoderLib.

Consider the tree that your simple example produces:

```
$ scons -n -Q --tree=all -f ex.sc config=1
scons: `build_packages' is up to date.
+-build_packages
  +-bar.txt
  | +-hello, world

  +-transcoderLib
    +-foo.txt
      +-hello, world
```

As you can see, `build_packages` depends upon `bar.txt` due to the `env.Alias()` call. `build_packages` also depends upon `transcoderLib`, due to the `Depends()` calls. But there is no relationship between `bar.txt` and `transcoderLib`.

If `bar.txt` *does* depend upon `transcoderLib`, then that relationship needs to be expressed:

```
Depends('bar.txt', env.Alias('transcoderLib'))
```

If that line is added to your example, the resulting tree is:

```
$ scons -Q --tree=all -f ex1.sc config=1
scons: `build_packages' is up to date.
+-build_packages
  +-bar.txt
  | +-hello, world

  | +-transcoderLib
  |   +-foo.txt
  |     +-hello, world

  +-transcoderLib
    +-foo.txt
      +-hello, world
```

Comment: This is enlightening. I'd love to hear an alternative route that I can use for grouping targets, since Alias doesn't seem to work. The various packages I am building are in separate SConscripts, so going through each one and having it depend on the 'transcoderLib' is doable, but annoying. Do you know of any way to group those package targets together so I can set a dependency once on the entire group?

Comment: This didn't work. The dependency shows up under each package now, but it doesn't build 'transcoderLib' correctly - i.e. it builds it differently from how it would build it if I just ran the alias 'transcoderLib'.

Comment: I posted a more accurate SConstruct above